# Modifying an individual element in an array inside of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have to write a piece of code for a class that counts the occurrences of characters within an input file and then sorts them by that, and I chose to do that by creating an ArrayList where each object[] has two elements, the character and the number of occurrences.

I was trying to increment the integer representing the number of occurrences and I just couldn't get that to work

My current attempt looks like this:

```
  for(int i=0;i<=text.length();i++) {
        if(freqlist.contains(text.charAt(i))) {
            freqlist.indexOf(text.charAt(i))[1]=freqlist.get(freqlist.indexOf(text.charAt(i)))[1]+1;
        }

    }
```

text is just a string containing all of the input file

freqlist is declared earlier as

```
List<Object[]> freqlist=new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

So, I was wondering how one could increment or modify an element of an array that is inside of an arraylist

Comment: It looks like you're trying to treat the list elements both as characters and as Object[2] arrays.

Comment: You should try using a map where the keys are the character and the values are the number of occurrences.  You can use the merge method to update the count.

Comment: It would probably be easier to track the counts using a `Map<Character, Integer>`.  The sorting part is not clear.  Or stream `text`, using grouping.

Answer (score 0):

In General there are 3 mistakes in your program which prevent it from working. It cannot work because the for loop has `i<=text.length()` and it should be `i < text.length()`, otherwise you will have exception. Second mistake is that you use `freqlist.contains(...)` where you assume both elements of object arrays are the same, or in other words the array is the equal, which is wrong assumption. Third mistake is using freqlist.indexOf(...) which relies on array equality again. I made the example working although this data structure `List<Object[]>` is inefficient for the task. It is best to use `Map<Character,Integer>`.
Here it is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "abcdacd";

        List<Object[]> freqlist= new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i < text.length();i++) {
            Object [] objects = find(freqlist, text.charAt(i));
            if(objects != null) {
                objects[1] = (Integer)objects[1] +1;
            } else {
                freqlist.add(new Object[]{text.charAt(i), 1});
            }

        }

        for (Object[] objects : freqlist) {
            System.out.println(String.format(" %s  =>  %d", objects[0], objects[1]));
        }
    }

    private static Object[] find(List<Object[]> freqlist, Character charAt) {
        for (Object[] objects : freqlist) {
            if (charAt.equals(objects[0])) {
                return objects;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is first parse the file and convert it to an array of characters. This would then be sent to the charCounter() method which would count the number of times a letter occurs in the file.

```
/**
     * Calculate the number of times a character is present in a character array
     *
     * @param myChars An array of characters from an input file, this should be parsed and formatted properly
     *                before sending to method
     * @return A hashmap of all characters with their number of occurrences; if a
     *                letter is not in myChars it is not added to the HashMap
     */
    public HashMap<Character, Integer> charCounter(char[] myChars) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> myCharCount = new HashMap<>();
        if (myChars.length == 0) System.exit(1);
        for (char c : myChars) {
            if (myCharCount.containsKey(c)) {
                //get the current number for the letter
                int currentNum = myCharCount.get(c);

                //Place the new number plus one to the HashMap
                myCharCount.put(c, (currentNum + 1));
            } else {
                //Place the character in the HashMap with 1 occurrence
                myCharCount.put(c, 1);
            }
        }
        return myCharCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some Stream magic, if you are using Java 8 for the grouping:

```
Map<String, Long> map = dummyString.chars() // Turn the String to an IntStream
        .boxed() // Turn int to Integer to use Collectors.groupingBy
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Character::toString,     // Use the character as a key for the map
                Collectors.counting())); // Count the occurrences
```

Now you could sort the result.